# HTML & CSS images and text align

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to align this pictures inline in CSS, and to put the text under them.
They should look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mozs.png)

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
            <div id="featured">
                <h2>Meet our Animals</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="first">
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Duis laoreet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"  class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Curabitur</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Adipiscing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Sed Volutpat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Nulla lobortis</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Suspendisse</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Tincidunt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last">
                        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
                        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Is it possible to do it without flexbox just using inline-block ?
Here is the CSS:

```
#content{
    height: 150px;
}
#content #featured a{
  
}
#content #featured li{
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.grid_thumbnails{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    background: url("../images/penguin.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please add your css code ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68214141/edit) your question to include those details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic reason of not getting aligned is you are targeting your li selector in this block of code

```
`#content #featured li{
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: inline-block; /* Here is the issue exclude li from this group and style it separately  */
}`
```

problem is with

```
`display: inline-block;`
```

of li tag it must be like following

```
`li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}`
```

also align your ul to row direction

```
`ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}`
```

I also edited your code on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/MuhammadUsmanAslam/pen/VwbLbmq) check it out and see difference

Answer (score 0):

You could change your structure like this

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails">
        <figure>
            <picture>
               <img scr="" alt= "Adipiscing">
            </picture>
            <figcaption>Adipiscing</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is a full demo using [text-align: center;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) and [display: inline-block;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
[id=featured] ul{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}
[id=featured] ul li{ 
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
 <div id="content">
    <div id="featured">
        <h2>Meet our Animals</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="first">
                <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails">
                    <figure>
                    <picture>
                        <img scr="" alt="Duis laoreet">
                    </picture>
                    <figcaption>Duis laoreet</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails">
                    <figure>
                    <picture>
                        <img scr="" alt="Curabitur">
                    </picture>
                    <figcaption>Curabitur</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
            </li> 

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails">
                    <figure>
                    <picture>
                        <img scr="" alt= "Adipiscing">
                    </picture>
                    <figcaption>Adipiscing</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> The **`float`** CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute_positioning)).

Apply [`float:left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#values) on all list items like so:

```css
#content {
  height: 150px;
}

#content #featured ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

#content #featured li {
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.grid_thumbnails {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  background: url("../images/penguin.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="featured">
    <h2>Meet our Animals</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="first">
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Duis laoreet</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Curabitur</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Adipiscing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Sed Volutpat</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Nulla lobortis</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Suspendisse</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Tincidunt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
        <a href="#" class="grid_thumbnails"></a>
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```